# Visual Studio Code ignores typescript version settings

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I cannot get Visual Studio Code to update the version of typescript it is running.

I have read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it) in detail.

I have tried setting my user settings to:

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "C:\\Users\\myUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
}
```

This did not help.

I have also tried setting my workspace setting to:

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

This also seemed to have no effect.

I configured my task runner to run tasks.json and have it set to the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "args": ["-v"],
    "echoCommand": true
}
```

This will call tsc with the -v command (to output the version).

When I press ctrl+shift+B the output reads

> running command> tsc -v
>   Version 1.8.34

**Is there something else I need to do to get Visual Studio Code to update its version of Typescript?**

NOTE: I went to both of the paths I tried above and did a *tsc -v* in the bin folder and both returned 2.1.4

NOTE II: I have tried restarting Visual Studio Code several times.

NOTE III: When I run *tsc -v* from a command prompt from *C:* it outputs 2.1.4

I am running Visual Studio Code 1.8.1

Update:

I changed my tasks.json to run *where tsc* and this was the output:

> running command> where tsc
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.js
>   C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
>   C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd

So I can see where it is getting the older version of typescript from, but I don't understand WHY it is not using the "overridden" version.

My only guess is that the override is not for building.  It is only for intelisense and such.  **Still, I need a way to change this...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on TypeScript and JavaScript support in VSCode.

The `typescript.tsdk` sets the version of TypeScript used inside VSCode for IntelliSense. It does not impact which version of `tsc` used for running the tasks. The tasks use the same logic as the command line to resolve `tsc`.

To use your local copy of `tsc` in the task, change the `task.json` to:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "args": ["-v"],
    "echoCommand": true
}
```

or, on windows:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\tsc.cmd",
    "args": ["-v"],
    "echoCommand": true
}
```

Hope that helps clear things up. Please [let us know](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues) if have any ideas for making the documentation of this more clear, or you can even [submit a PR to improve the docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/languages/typescript.md).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I had tried something similar and could not get it to work.  When I put in what you suggested I got an error.  Adding in `isShellCommand` as true gave me the error message:  *'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*  I tried to take out the leading '.' (and some other combinations) but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Since you are windows, you have to use a windows style path: `.\\node_modules\\.bin\\tsc.cmd`. I've updated the answer to show this as well.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much!

Comment: I am using VSCode and I no longer have the ability to switch Typescript version. I don't see the current version in the bottom right toolbar, and I don't see a menu for Typescript version either. I have lost all intellisense. Tried to downgrade to 1.3 version of VSCode but see the exact same behaviour. I tried to google which leads me down the path of setting typescript.tsdk but to no avail! @MattBierner do you have any ideas why this may be so?

Comment: It sounds like the built-in `JavaScript and TypeScript language features` extension is disabled. In the extensions view, search `@builtin` to make sure it is enabled