# How to resolve error "constructors in/after an Optional Chain are not allowed"

Tags: babeljs, optional-chaining

I meet a problem when I'm integrating plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`, and it throws error like this:

> constructors in/after an Optional Chain are not allowed.

How to resolve this problem? Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: I encountered this problem also, but it went away after bumping up my version of Babel (and possibly other packages related to Babel). Also note that VSCode isn't using Typescript 3.7 yet, so you'll still get errors showing above. For more info, there's already a great stackoverflow post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it