# Webpack cant compile ts 3.7 (Optional Chaining, Nullish Coalescing)

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I try to use `typescript 3.7` features like Optional Chaining, Nullish Coalescing. But `webpack` gives me an error while transpaling.

```
app: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (50:40)
app: File was processed with these loaders:
app:  * ../../../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
app: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
app: | export const Layout = (props) => {
app: |     const regionsResults = useQuery(regionsQuery, { fetchPolicy: 'cache-first' });
app: >     const regions = regionsResults.data?.regions ?? [];
app: |     const userItem = useQuery(usersProfileQuery, { fetchPolicy: 'cache-first' });
app: |     const handleOnClick = (selected) => props.history.push(selected.key);
``
```

Comment: can you post your `packages.json` file?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I changed target: `esnext` to `es2018` in `tsconfig.json` file. Now it works.

Webpack issue for reference : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227

Comment: This did not work for me. Webpack still fails with the same error.

Comment: Does not work if you are using `"foo".matchAll(/o+/g)` cause it's a ES2020 feature.

Comment: This is ridiculous, but it really works! I even can't figure out how... Optional channing brought to us only since ES2020. ES2018 & ES2019 are both works properly, btw ES2020 is still crashing.

Comment: So is the issue that Webpack cannot parse ES2020 code? That sucks.

Comment: @Timmmm Not webpack but acorn apparently (see the GitHub issue above) which is confusing because the code runs on Node, and optional chaining is already supported in Node 14.

Comment: In tsconfig.json I added "target: "ES2019" " where there was no target attribute. This did the trick.

Comment: I thought esnext always targets the latest? Guess not

Answer (score 35):

Depending on which loader you're using to transiple the code, there are several options available

For **`ts-loader`**, you need to make sure the output from typescript is understandable by Webpack. This can be achieved by setting `target` to `ES2018` in `tsconfig.json`.

For **`babel-loader`**, you'll need to make sure babel loads the

- `@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator`
- `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`

plugins.
Note that if you're using `preset-env`, it may or may not load these plugins depending on your `targets` or `browserlist` (ie, won't be loaded if the target env has support for these language features), in which case the only way to guarantee their inclusion is by manually specifying them in the `plugins` array in `babel.config.js`,

```
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
  ],
```

Comment: Is there a reference that says which versions of ECMAScript Webpack can parse? I.e. where does it say Webpack can parse ES2018 but not ES2020?

Comment: Webpack uses [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) as its parser ([package.json](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/a694cdfb82b5fd0a5c52102083a267a36446e03e/package.json#L13)), which determines the language features that are understood

Comment: I'm using babel-loader. And I correctly put the 2 plugins in the file because these syntax are working for my own files. But for node_modules files it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in an old Vue.js 2 web app.

I had to do the following:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining
```

And modify my `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@vue/app"],
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator", "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining"],
};
```

See:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator#installation
- https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining#installation

Answer (score -6):

If you're using vs code, probably you should change the local typescript version vs code use.

[What TypeScript version is Visual Studio Code using? How to update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it)