# Expression expected.ts(1109) after TypeScript upgrade to 3.7.2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I upgraded TypeScript to 3.7.2 from 3.6.x. And write code using optional chaining.
But get strange error

> Expression expected.ts(1109)

in (vim, VSCode) IDE, even when build was successful.

[image]

Comment: "I upgraded typescript to 3.7.2" from...?

Comment: I believe the answer you're looking for can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your editor isn't using TypeScript 3.7 yet - see if there are options for using the TypeScript version in the TSServer from from your node_modules.

Comment: Do you mean options in IDE?

Answer (score 20):

Click the version in the bottom right of VS Code.

[image: TS Version]

A dropdown will appear at the top with a few options such as "Use VS Code's Version" and "Use Workspace Version".

Select "*Use Workspace Version*" which will select the version of typescript that `tsc` is using, typically installed in your `devDependencies`.

This will automatically add a line to your [Workspace Configuration File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676350/266535) that looks something like the following:

```
{
   "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start using TypeScript 3.7 features in VS Code today by installing the [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next).

Comment: Or click typescript version number on status bar. select typescript version.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker'
import newdate 

export default () ={'>'} {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

  return <DatePicker date={date} onDateChange={setDate} />
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).