# typescript null safe operators errors. I am using mac and visul code

Tags: typescript, operators

Hello does anyone know why am i getting errors while using null sage operators in typescript? How to solve this problem? I am using visual code(mac).

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expression expected.ts(1109) after TypeScript upgrade to 3.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58820889/expression-expected-ts1109-after-typescript-upgrade-to-3-7-2)

Answer (score 0):

You should check which version of TypeScript you are using. Optional chaining operator was introduced in `version 3.7`.

[TypeScript 3.7 Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

Comment: Hi tnx for anwser. I just did 'npm install -g typescript' and still getting this error.

Comment: I just checked. My typscript version:  "typescript": "~3.7.5"

Comment: Can you copy the error message you get?

Comment: Expression expected. ':' expected.

Comment: The version of TypeScript you provided in the comment above is, I assume, from your package.json file. You should check if VS Code itself is using this version. You can see this in the bottom right corner of VS Code when you have some TS file open.

Comment: Ah yes i see. That was the problem tnx man. Sry i can't upvote you or anything stupid admins wont let me.