# "Parsing error: Argument expression expected. eslint" with Typescript map function in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

From this line of code

```
{inputFields.map(if => <Input inputField={if} /> )}
```

I am getting this error on the word map

```
Parsing error: Argument expression expected.eslint
```

inputFields is inside a form, which is inside a div

```
<div>
    <form>
        {inputFields.map...}
    </form>
</div
```

And input fields is an array

```
inputFields: InputField[]
```

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58821005/6331353) suggests that this could have something to do with the typescript version.

In my `package.json`, I have that I'm using `"typescript": "^3.8.3"`, but in the bottom right, I think it's saying that I'm using version 4.0.2?

[image]

When I click on that number, I can change the number to `3.9.7` but that doesn't change the error

---

Other answers that I've seen are not relevant to my use case with the map function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if` is a keyword in Javascript. Try renaming your variable:

```js
{inputFields.map(field => <Input inputField={field} /> )}
```

**Statements vs Expressions**

An expression is code that resolves to a value

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b
add(10, 20) // => 30 
'Hello' // => 'Hello'
```

A statement is code that makes something happen

```js
if (x < 10) // doesn't resolve
break // doesn't resolve
switch // doesn't resolve
```

Therefore the warning: "“Parsing error: Argument expression expected. eslint” is telling you that an expression (something that resolves to a value) is expected but instead you have passed a statement (which cannot be resolved to a value)

You cannot assign a statement to a variable, only expressions.

Comment: Yeah that did it, sorry about that, just wasn't clueing in. I'll accept your answer but SO is telling me I have to wait 5 minutes

Comment: Don't worry about it. Does the "Parsing error: Argument expression expected.eslint" warning make sense now?

Comment: No, it's still kinda jargon to me. Is it saying that the map function is expecting an argument, but I'm passing it an if statement, which doesn't count as an argument?

Comment: You are pretty much right, I've updated the answer which should clear up your confusion.

Comment: Thanks, the extra explanation helps

Comment: Thank you, also works with other reserved words (I was trying to do `imports.map(import => /* ... */)`)

Answer (score 1):

you  cant use a variable with a keyword that holding in the language like if or var as the variable  in js so you need to rename the name of the variable as you want it should work

```
{inputFields.map((data)=> <Input inputField={data} /> )}
```