# Getting error ts(1109) and ts(1005) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting the errors `ts(1109) and ts(1005)`.

```
 <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label className={errors.email && 'text-danger'}>
          {errors.email ?? 'Email address'}
        </Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="email"
          value={variables.email}
          className={errors.email && 'is-invalid'}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setVariables({ ...variables, email: e.target.value })
          }
        />
</Form.Group>
```

I am getting the errors for

```
{errors.email ?? 'Email address'}
```

can anyone please tell me how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you trying to make a ternary operator here ```{errors.email ?? 'Email address'}```?

Comment: Nullish Coalescing operator is supported after version 3.7, make sure your typescript version is supporting that. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58821005/4354624

Comment: I'm assuming its supposed to a ternary 
{errors.email ? 'Email address':'false case'}

or if ?? is intentional
Babel 7.8.0 or CRA 3.3.0 or above

Comment: @yudhiesh I am trying to write, if there are no errors, then show Email address.

Comment: @Tanish you can do `errors.email || 'Email address'` which return `'Email address'` if `errors.email` is `falsy`.  while `{errors.email ?? 'Email address'}` return  `'Email address'` if `errors.email` is `null` or `undefined`.