# Suppressing Visual Studio Code "[ts] Expression Expected" false positive?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

In the example code below, when I have "formatOnSave" enabled (which I prefer), for every instance of "n?.", it automatically converts it to "n ?."

Is it possible to create an exception handler to prevent this replacement but keep "formatOnSave" enabled?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're using an old version of vs code or an old version of typescript.

Comment: Actually, I just found the answer > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58820889/expression-expected-ts1109-after-typescript-upgrade-to-3-7-2

Comment: Just had to change the typescript version setting in the code editor to use the workspace version instead of VS Code version