# TypeScript Error : Unexpected token `div`. Expected jsx identifier

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I was building a website based on nextjs-typescript and tailwindcss

and I am encountering this weird error `Expression expected`.

[image: screenshot of error]

I am also getting this in the terminal:

```bash
  Unexpected token `div`. Expected jsx identifier
  const UseCases = () => {
  7 |   return (
  8 |     <div className="relative z-10 bg-gray-100 py-20">
    :      ^^^
  9 |       <FadeIntoView>
```

This is my code

```js
import dataUseCases from "../../data/cases.data"
import FadeIntoView from "../../utils/gsap/fadeIntoView"

import Cases from "./useCases"

const UseCases = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative z-10 bg-gray-100 py-20">
      <FadeIntoView>
        <h2 className="xs:text-8xl text-22vw fill-color pb-7 text-right font-black">Case</h2>
        <div>
          {dataUseCases.map((case, index) => (<Cases key={case.title + "-" + index} index={index + 1}  />))}
        </div>
      </FadeIntoView>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UseCases
```

and the file is named `index.tsx` and is located inside `src/components/useCase`

Tsconfig:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I tried a few suggestions from

[swc#issue-2237](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/2237)
[stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58820889/expression-expected-ts1109-after-typescript-upgrade-to-3-7-2)

But none of them seem to work here

Comment: What happens if you surround the `<div>` (and all the return value) in `<>` and `</>`?

Comment: You've mashed two completely different error messages which should be two questions into a single question here. You should expect your question to be closed as "Needs more focus". You should edit it to focus on one problem, then consider asking another question about your other problem.

Answer (score 4):

`case` is a reserved keyword in javascript change that variable in your map to something else

Comment: the "Expected JSX Identifier" error is actually kind of a misnomer... the JSX component is there, but has an error within it... so the compiler is confused and thinks the jsx isn't even there (because it can't identify it as a jsx component) 

So once you remove the former issue, the latter should go away. 
I have these "JSX Identifer" errors when i add a prop with an empty value or have an egregious typo somewhere in the code (an errant symbol somewhere)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

For me it says - "Unexpected token `header`", but the actual problem in missing parameter on a property

Comment: this was my issue, thank you!

Comment: haha, nextjs error reporting is amusing.

Answer (score 2):

> break  byte    case    catch
> char    class*  const   continue
> debugger    default delete  do
> double  else    enum*   eval
> export* extends*    false   final
> finally float   for function
> goto    if  implements  import*
> in  instanceof  int interface
> let*    long    native  new
> null    package private protected
> public  return  short   static
> super*  switch  synchronized    this
> throw   throws  transient   true
> try typeof  var void abstract   arguments   await*  boolean
> volatile    while   with    yield

all these `keywords` are reserved in javaScript you cannot use them as variables, labels, or function names

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside

```
<></>
```

like this:

```
const UseCases = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative z-10 bg-gray-100 py-20">
        <FadeIntoView>
          <h2 className="xs:text-8xl text-22vw fill-color pb-7 text-right font-black">Case</h2>
          <div>
            {dataUseCases.map((case, index) => (<Cases key={case.title + "-" + index} index={index + 1}  />))}
          </div>
        </FadeIntoView>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You'll end up with the same issue