# Why doesn't VS Code report an error that the command line tsc does?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

If I intentionally make a typo in my code I will get an error. Here is the correct code:

```
declare const State: TwineState;
```

If I delete the last character and then type tsc on the command line, it gives me this error:

```
tsc/prod.spec.ts:7:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TwineStat'.

7 declare const State: TwineStat;
```

But Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to realize there's any error.

[image]

How I get my editor to show me the same errors that the tsc command recognizes? I'm pretty new to all these technologies so I don't know what information would be helpful to troubleshoot, but here are my config files:

package.json:

```
{
...
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "scripts": {
    "compile-typescript": "tsc && cp tscbuild/prod.js story/",
    "lint": "eslint tsc/** --fix",
    "test": "npm run lint && ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine && npm run compile-typescript ..."
  },
  "keywords": [],
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.9",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testcafe": "^0.2.1",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "testcafe": "^1.8.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "typescript": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es6","dom"],                           /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": false,                         /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "tscbuild",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "tsc",                         /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                    /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                /* Include modules imported with '.json' extension */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    jasmine: true,
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:testcafe/recommended"
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly"
  },
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "testcafe"],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
    "no-plusplus": ["off"],
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": ["off"]
  }
};
```

Comment: Sounds like TS Server got confused. If you restart it do the errors show up? (Command Pallet -> Restart TS Server)

Comment: Even though it's deprecated, I've had good luck using the TSLint plugin concurrently with ESLint.  Also, did you have to manually install the `@typescript-eslint` plugin, or does listing it in `eslintrc` result in automatic usage?  I'm not sure how to actually integrate them.

Comment: @Gerrit0 I ran that and it had no effect. Restarting Visual Studio has no effect either

Comment: @Tedskovsky I don't know enough to confidently answer your questions, but from skimming https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin#installation it looks like I've installed it the way the official docs say to. Since I have posted the configs, haven't I provided enough information to answer that question?

Comment: if I recall (and that's a big if), the problem went away when I switched from one project back to this one. It was not fixed by restarting the application.

Comment: A possible reason is that you forgot to add the `.ts` files into `"includes"` array in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I encountered this issue with only a specific TS error (everything else worked fine). Turned out it was VSCode's version of TS vs my project's version (and this answer helped fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676463)

Answer (score 4):

There are probably a number of reasons that this happens. This sometimes happens to me and I can't explain why this happens but I have noticed that the `incremental` feature/flag in `tsconfig.json` can cause the transpiler to cache outdated data which would cause these differences. It appears that VSCode might not use the `incremental` cached data and the command line does.

There are two ways to test and fix this. One is the flip the flag for incremental in the tsconfig.json to `false`. When I've done this the errors will appear on the command line. Problem is that when you flip it back to `true` those errors then disappear. The other option is delete your `outDir` - often called `dist/` or `build/` or something similar.

A third option that I haven't confirmed is to delete the `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file only which is usually in the `outDir` as well. There's a setting in tsconfig.json called `tsBuildInfoFile` that will redirect this file to whatever value you specify for that prop so if you can't find it in the outDir try that location.

Comment: I skipped ahead and deleted my local /dist first, which caused my transpiler to trip on a different verifiably nonsensical error, then toggled the `incremental` flag as you suggested and I'm back up and running. I work in (too) many subtly differently configured repos, but I've never had errant TS errors "stick" like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for the discrepancy between VS Code problem reporting and command line `tsc` error reporting is coming from the fact that **VS Code uses your modifications even if you haven't saved them**.

As an example, if you modify an interface but don't save the file, VS Code may report errors for incompatible types whereas `tsc` is using the saved file without modifications and is happy with no problems. Especially the pinned files have quite small modified-icon which can remain unnoticed as I learned the hard way.

Comment: in my case, autosave is on.

Answer (score 0):

for me instead of running tsc i used a custom script in my package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    ....
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
},
```

not sure why it works.