# Vscode React Giving Property 'button' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I was trying to create my first React app with vs code. It was underlining all the HTML in the .tsx files. and giving me the error `Property 'button' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
I was able to resolve this issue by going to the bottom right of vs code and clicking the {} and then going to select the version and changing it to Use Workspace version.

Comment: you mean the typescript version? if so, what version of VS Code do you have installed, and what version of typescript is your workspace using? also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470675/11107541