# Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'

Tags: typescript, rxjs

i use rxjs with typescript but i got the next  ERROR

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'.'C:/Path/to/project/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/index.js'

typescript version 4.7.4 

rxjs version 7.5.6

working with vscode 1.59
```

i create new angular 14 app.
to solve this i tried to upgrade the typescript version like i saw inw the github issue that it solved afer typescript 4.2 and above
but i still have the error

how to solve the versiong problem ?

Answer (score 2):

the error was show only  on the vscode and not on the **tsc** in  the terminal.
so i understood that the problem was in the **vscode typescript internal server.**  . it has older typescript version then rxjs 7 need....
so i upgrade th vscode version to 1.69 and it was solved

you also can change the vscode ts version manually
see this answer
[What TypeScript version is Visual Studio Code using? How to update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it)

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same error message but it was just in IntelliJ, the project compiled and ran just fine.
[image: Error when hovering]

The issue was, that IntelliJ found an older Typescript version from a different frontend.

After assigning the correct TypeScript and restarting the TypeScript Service(bottom right of the editor) the error went away.

[image: Restart ts service]

If you are using 7.5.4: just update (source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6822)