# Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder' inTypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-mediarecorder

I am building vue3js web typescript project. And I need to save user's camera and microphone after when user click the button. My node version is 16.14.0 and MediaRecorder is not working.

There is not syntax error before running project but vscode says "cannot find name 'MediaRecorder' && cannot find name 'BlobEvent'.." when I run my project. I search another alternatives but everybody write that "there is not alternative, you have to use MediaRecorder." How can i make runable this?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ai-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "rtl": "webpack --config webpack-rtl.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "^5.9.0",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^5.9.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.1",
    "@soerenmartius/vue3-clipboard": "^0.1.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.0",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "^1.2.5",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "^3.23.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.23.1",
    "array-sort": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.4.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "dropzone": "^5.7.2",
    "element-plus": "^1.0.2-beta.52",
    "i18n": "^0.13.3",
    "line-awesome": "^1.3.0",
    "nouislider": "^14.6.3",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "prism-themes": "^1.5.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.23.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rtlcss-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.6",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.10.12",
    "vee-validate": "^4.2.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.2",
    "vue-clipboard3": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-currency-input": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.6",
    "vue-inline-svg": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "vue-prism-component": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.2.1",
    "vue3-clipboard": "^1.0.0",
    "vue3-highlightjs": "^1.0.5",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dom-mediacapture-record": "^1.0.19",
    "@types/prismjs": "^1.16.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "1.32.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

And my errors:

```
You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://192.168.111.8:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run yarn build.

ERROR in src/ui/views/crafted/authentication/basic-flow/ChatWithAI.vue:417:35
TS2552: Cannot find name 'MediaRecorder'. Did you mean 'mediaRecorder'?
    415 |         });
    416 |
  > 417 |         const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
        |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    418 |         let audioChunks: Blob[];

ERROR in src/ui/views/crafted/authentication/basic-flow/ChatWithAI.vue:421:65
TS2304: Cannot find name 'BlobEvent'.
  > 421 |         mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event: BlobEvent) => {
        |                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
    422 |           const blobData = event.data;
    423 |           if (blobData && blobData.size > 0) {
    424 |             audioChunks.push(blobData);
```

I wish these commands worked, no one had such problems...

Comment: Your typescript version is pretty old (~4.1.5), and typescript [didn't always have the types for MediaRecorder included](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34728#issuecomment-913241426).  You probably need at least version 4.5, but might as well upgrade to latest 5.3.

Comment: I've tried but does not work... My package version's are too old because web template i  use is very old.. How can i solve this problem.. @yoduh

Comment: What do you mean you tried? **What did you try exactly**?  Give specific details.  What upgrade command did you run? Did you get the latest version or something else? Did you verify your version of TypeScript afterward was what you upgraded to? I verified myself your issue exists with 4.1.5 and does not exist 5.3, so the solution is to upgrade.  Maybe your local vs global version of TypeScript is at fault, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676463/6225326) for more details.

Comment: Tried "npm i @typescript@latest" but doesn't work. Too many errors occurred. Then I researched other ts versions. It worked when I installed the popular version 4.5.2. Thank u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried update my project's typescript version and solved the problem.

Just tried:

```
npm i typescript@4.5.2
```

This is working.