# Weird typescript error on wildcard from tsconfig.base.json custom lib paths

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a NX monorepo with the following structure:

```
apps/
├── api/
│   ├── src/
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tsconfig.lib.json
└── client/
    ├── src
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── tsconfig.lib.json
libs/
├── api/
│   ├── src/
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tsconfig.lib.json
├── ui/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── button/
│   │   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   │   └── Button.tsx
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tsconfig.lib.json
└── shared/
    └── ...
tsconfig.base.json
```

```
tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@name/api": ["libs/api/src/index.ts"],
      "@name/ui/*": [
        "libs/ui/src/*"
      ],
  },
  "exclude": ["tmp"]
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    }
  ],
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}

tsconfig.lib.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.jsx", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

All components are exported via index.ts if it needs to be exposed to other projects.

Imports are done like `@name/ui/folder`. Where every folder has index.ts barrel file. The code runs perfectly but the projects where the import gets imported that project's tsconfig keeps on complaining.

TS keeps complaining about the path for @name/ui/* giving this error multiple times:

```
File '/workspace/libs/ui/src/*/index.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

I did some basic research and I think putting a file after a wildcard is valid, and the code does work. I just hope I can get rid of this specific error. Any help is appreciated!

Original Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/138rvsn/ts_keeps_throwing_file_not_found_root_file/

Yes I restarted my IDE Typescript server etc. It comes back as soon as I start editing a file. I removed the wild card in the path and it goes away, But I need to support this with a wild card.

Plesse help

Answer (score 0):

> The code runs perfectly but the projects where the import gets imported that project's tsconfig keeps on complaining

Unless I'm mistaken, typescript would have to compile for the code to run. I'm going to guess that you're seeing an error in your IDE/editor, but if you run the code directly it works just fine.

Given that assumption, are you using VSCode? If yes, there are 2 ideas that come to mind:

1. I've personally had some weird issues with the VSCode IDE reading tsconfig.json, and sometimes I've had to do a modified tsconfig just for vscode. You could specify a `tsconfig.json` in the root of your overall folder structure and remove the `files`, `include`, and `exclude` params ([see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12563#issuecomment-249502707)) for vscode only. You wouldn't use this file to build; it's just for the IDE.
2. VSCode can run a different version of Typescript compiler than what is in the codebase. See [VSCode Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-the-workspace-version-of-typescript) and [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731/what-typescript-version-is-visual-studio-code-using-how-to-update-it). Maybe try making sure the IDE is on the same version of Typescript?

Hope this helps!

Comment: My auto import will fail then?

Answer (score 0):

Change your path mapping to specify the exact directories instead of using a wildcard, because wildcard path (`*`) is not supported in ts's module resolution system.

```
"paths": {
 "@name/api": ["libs/api/src/index.ts"],
 "@name/ui/button": ["libs/ui/src/button/index.ts"],
 // other mappings
},
```

Then, import the ```Button component like:

```
import { Button } from '@name/ui/button';
```

Comment: I have almost 800 of these components. this design is not possible. I need the *

Comment: While ts supports wildcard ```*```, it doesn't mean it can fully support all scenarios especially when combined with ```index.ts```. As ts's wildcard support is limited, fo me, there is no direct solution to it. But instead of using wildcard paths in ```tsconfig.json```, try to create a single ```index.ts``` in each subdirectory under ```libs/ui/src/``` and re-export everything from there. Then, in ```tsconfig.json```, map ```@name/ui/*``` to ```libs/ui/src/index.ts```. This way, ts should able to find the ```index.ts``` files without explicitly specifying them in the paths config.

Comment: Yes I tried that approach too. The problem is that that common folder had some backend module like database mongoose, now somehow in that approach the whole angular breaks when I try to import anything from it. I have some common logic that is required in FE and in BE. That was weird as hell. Anyways I will keep the question as open. Maybe someone did have some luck. Thank you for the answer