Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'defineAsyncComponent'
I am trying to convert a large Vue3 app, using the Options API, to TypeScript and am running into a few difficulties. I wonder if someone might give me some guidance. I understand that it is recommended to use the Composition API in conjunction with TypeScript, but sadly that is not an option - the app is already using the Options API and there is no appetite for migrating to the Composition API.
To get started I scaffolded out a new Vu3 + TypeScript app using create-vue and then copied the configs over to the existing app. I also installed any dependencies the existing app was missing which seemed related to TypeScript (e.g @vue/tsconfig and vue-tsc).
Following this, the app appears to be working as expected (serve is working and I can run the app in the browser).
However, as soon as change the script tag in any .vue file to be lang="ts" then any imports from 'vue' are underlined by VSCode. For example, defineAsyncComponent is underlined and VSCode reports that "module 'vue' has no exported member 'defineAsyncComponent'" which is clearly not correct as, if I open the Vue d.ts file in VSCode I can see the declaration for defineAsyncComponent is definitely exported. Plus the app still runs in the browser without issue.
I don't have many extensions installed in VScode, but I do have the official Vue extension, as well as Vetur Extended. I have tried disabling both of these but without the official Vue extension enabled, I don't get any intellisense or even code-colouring in VSCode at all, so I can't even see if the imports are recognised. Disabling only the Vetur Extended extension does not resolve the issue.
It is only Vue imports that have this issue, other 3rd party imports are not underlined, and I can ctrl+click to jump to the associated d.ts file.
What am I missing? How can I make VSCode see things exported from Vue correctly?
For ref, here is my configs:
tsconfig.json
{
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo"
  }
}

package.json (relevant parts only)
"dependencies": {
    "vite-plugin-require": "1.2.14",
    "vue": "3.5.6",
    "vue-i18n": "10.0.1",
    "vue-router": "4.4.5",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^22.8.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "5.1.3",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "3.5.0",
    "sass": "1.79.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "vite": "5.4.6",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.1.10"
}

Edit
I should probably mention, in the reference app I scaffolded out to get the config from initially, I can import defineAsyncComponent without any issues, and VSCode does not underline it. I'm not saying definitely that VSCode is not the issue here, but it seems unlikely given that the ref app doesn't have the same issue when opened with the same version of VScode (with the same extensions). FWIW, I'm using the latest version of VSCode at the time of posting this question (version 1.95.2)
Edit 2
I noticed another difference - in the scaffolded reference app, the tsconfig.app.json does not have the noEmit option set. In the app I am trying to get TypeScript working properly in, if I don't set "noEmit": false then the main tsconfig.json gets an error in the references config which says "tsconfig.app.json may not disable emit".

Does the app build correctly, including vue-tsc check? Then the problem is specific to vsc, which the question doesn't cover. It could be it or the plugin that is outdated, or it uses old ts version

Well, if I run vue-tsc --build --force, it finds a bunch of type errors across the app (which I kind of expect at this point as I've literally just begin the conversion), but not for defineAsyncComponent. But I wouldn't expect to see an error for that, because defineAsyncComponent does obviously exist.

Then it's vsc problem. As said, it's primarily specific to versions, because there's not much you can do to affect this otherwise. For instance, if it uses old ts version, it will ignore any types that require new one

I should probably have mentioned that in the reference app I scaffolded out to get the config from initially, I can import defineAsyncComponent fine and VSCode doesn't show any warnings

It's unknown how reference and your app differ, so nothing could be suggested at this point. As I said, TS version that VSC uses would be one of the things to blame, check it if you didn't, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668731 . Consider publishing both projects so they could be debugged if possible

Yes, understood, sadly it is not possible to publish the app - it's closed source. I was just hoping it was something obvious I'd missed. Thanks

It doesn't need to contain proprietary code, just hello world with exactly same setup, and it needs to be possible to reproduce the problem when the deps are installed from scratch based on package lock file. If the project contains vscode config, it could contribute to the problem. No, you didn't miss anything, make sure you use latest vsc and volar and vsc's ts is configured to use project's ts

Sure, but the reference app I scaffolded out doesn't have this issue - vscode doesn't highlight the imports from vue. When you say to make sure VSC uses the project's TS file - I think it's using the root tsconfig.json file and not the tsconfig.app.json file - is this correct?

It's unknown how the apps differ, if you reinstalled deps, another set of them that causes problems could be installed. If vsc config is different somehow, this matters too. I mean not tsconfig but typescript package itself, see the link above for the explanation. It's responsible for the way ide handles ts files, i.e. the primary suspect

I notice in the working ref app, in an app file (like app.vue) the TypeScript button on the bar at the bottom of VSCode uses tsconfig.app.json, whereas in the app I am trying to get working, it shows the root tsconfig. Seems likely this could be the cause of some of the weirdness I'm seeing? How can I get VSCode to correctly use the tsconfig.app.json when viewing Vue files in the app?

Good you sorted this out. It remains unclear why chosen tsconfig was different between the projects. Did one had "files" and the other one not? The support of composite tsconfig ("references" field) depends on a tool, I've seen several cases of it not being properly supported, wouldn't expect problems from vsc. I can confirm that "files": [] is desirable in root composite config, I missed that part

No problems at all, thanks for your help :)

The config issue that I originally asked the question for - the error in Vue files that "Vue has no exported member 'defineAsyncComponent'" seems to be caused by removing the files option from the root tsconfig, even though the value for that option is just an empty array.
With "files": [] in the root tsconfig.json file, VSCode is able to use the correct tsconfig.app.json file when I open a .vue file, and imports from 'vue' are not underlined with red.
If I remove the files option from the root tsconfig, then VSCode reverts to using the root tsconfig rather than tsconfig.app and all the red underlining comes back for any .vue files.
So this aspect seems solved at least. I still have some other weird issues happening, but I'll open a more focused question for that issue.
